# Generate sine wave signal with time-varying frequency

Tags: trigonometry

I try to generate a sine wave signal with a frequency changing over time. The frequency is randomly defined by generating some random values in the range `[0.5, 2]` and interpolating the points between them.

The expected output signal is a sine wave with a non-changing amplitude and a changing frequency.
But there are some smaller bumps and the signal is not a 'smooth' sine wave. E.g. the period at `x = 200` should be larger than the period at `x = 10`, but the opposite is the case.

Does anyone know, what happened here?

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x_samples = np.arange(-100, 3100, 50)
freq_samples = np.random.random(x_samples.shape) * 1.5 + 0.5

x = np.arange(0, 3000, 0.1)
interpolation = interp1d(x_samples, freq_samples, kind='quadratic')
freq = interpolation(x)
y = np.sin(freq * x)

plt.plot(x, y, label="sin(freq(x) * x)")
plt.plot(x, freq, label="freq(x)")
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2k5Al.png)

Answer (score 0):

This is known as Frequency Modulation in Electronics. As you observed the variable crowding and loosening along time axis is its principal feature and is quite unlike the amplitude modulated wave.

The instantaneous frequency of carrier wave is variable and occurs in the wave expression argument inside the parenthesis, depending upon how argument ( carrier frequency) is modified.

Comment: Thank you. Do you have an idea, how a 'smooth' sine wave in sense of consistent amplitude can be achieved?

Comment: If the aspect ratio of the graph you attached is reduced, then a long  thin strip graph appears to have its crests and troughs smoothed out.